# Parts of a Docker command

Tags: docker

I came across the command `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`, which appeared to be a demonstration command to initialize a container. However, I am curious as to what the `80:80` does in regard to the overall command. What does this do? (If an answer to my question can be found in their documentation or some other resource, please do link it as I have done a good deal of searching around to no avail and am more than willing to do the reading myself. Thanks!)

Comment: Use `docker help <command>` (replace `<command>` with a Docker command) to learn about its parameters. Or read the [online documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT` flag binds your container port to the host port. In your case it's `80:80`, which the containers port 80 is bound to the port 80 of the host. (default is TCP)

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Answer (score 0):

based on `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

`docker run`:start your Container

`-d` detach your container when you start it

`-p 80:80`: map your container port to your host port that's mean when you connect to 80 port  host you are connect to 80 port container.Architecture is `-p {host_port}:{container_port}`

`docker/getting-started`:is your image name